# condition in where clause with optional parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

There are thee input parameter in my stored procedure. for example,

```
DECLARE @fromDate DateTime = NULL 
DECLARE @toDate DateTime = NULL
DECLARE @Id int = NULL
```

I want to write a condition in where clause like...if fromDate is provided then searching must be done on @fromDate. if @fromDate is not provided then check for @Id variable if this is not null then search basis on @Id...

Something like...

```
 where 
   CASE 
   when @fromDate is not null
  THEN (@FromDate is null or ([Created] between @FromDate and @ToDate))
    ELSE (@requestId is null or Id=@requestId)
```

there is one problem with below solution...if @fromDate and @Id both are provided then this will do intesect of them and nothing is return.....condition should be like...if @fromDate is given the priority gives to @fromDate even if @Id is provided and result must not be dependend to @Id parameter....

Comment: Why do you want to *support* the ability to pass a non-null `@fromDate` and `@Id` but then *ignore* one of them? If I was calling your procedure and passing values for both of them, I certainly wouldn't expect it to do what you describe.

Comment: Anyhow, the usual place to look for anything like this is Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you depend on both parameters you than can use them *both* in condition:

```
where
(@FromDate is null or ([Created] between @FromDate and @ToDate)) 
or
((@requestId is null or Id=@requestId) 
    and @FromDate is null) ----mix @requestId & @FromDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? Please check:

```
WHERE [Created] BETWEEN 
    (CASE WHEN @FromDate IS NOT NULL THEN @FromDate ELSE [Created] END) AND
    (CASE WHEN @ToDate IS NOT NULL THEN @ToDate ELSE [Created] END) AND
    Id=(CASE WHEN @requestId IS NOT NULL THEN @requestId ELSE Id END)
```